# Vuetify | V-alert :value just showing not closing when proterty is updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-alert component will show up / close base on a Vuex store - it will set error - and clear it after 4s !

And here is my V-alert component:

Problem is its `:value` not working when the `getError` become `null`

If I want my V-alert to disappear when the `getError` is `null`, I have to use `v-if`

My workaround is ok but I still confuse about `:value` in here

Is there a bug or I wrong somewhere?

```js
<template>
  <v-alert
    :value ="!!getError" // <~~~ Problem here

    transition="scroll-x-transition"

    :type="getError.type"
    :dismissible="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
    dense
    :prominent="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
    class="TrnAlert rounded-tr-xl rounded-bl-xl text-center text-caption text-md-body-1"
    @input="[CLEAR_ERROR]"
  >
    {{ getError.message }}
  </v-alert>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  import { CLEAR_ERROR } from '../../store/type/actions';

  export default {

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['getError']),
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions([CLEAR_ERROR]),
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Here is my store - it will set error - and clear it after 4s

```js
import { UPDATE_ERROR, REMOVE_ERROR } from '../type/mutations';
import { SET_ERROR, CLEAR_ERROR } from '../type/actions';

const state = () => ({
  error: null,
});

const getters = {
  getError: (state) => state.error,
};

const actions = {
  [SET_ERROR]({ commit }, payload) {
    commit(UPDATE_ERROR, payload);
    setTimeout(() => {
      commit(REMOVE_ERROR);
    }, 4000);

  },
  [CLEAR_ERROR]({ commit }) {
    commit(REMOVE_ERROR);
  },
};

const mutations = {
  [UPDATE_ERROR]: (state, payload) => {
    state.error = { message: payload.message, type: payload.type || 'error' };
  },
  [REMOVE_ERROR]: (state) => {
    state.error = null;
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
};
```

Comment: It should works fine. See my codesandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-carson-b838t

Comment: @User28 thanks for your time and your code, I will try to figure out what happened with my code,

And also thank you for an idea of writing snippet code in Codesanbox to debug, I will use it in the future,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to @User28 for his/her valuable working snippet code, it helps me to compare and figure out what happened to my stupid code,

Turn out, when Error has been removed on store, it made
 `state.error = null;`

and then make `:type="getError.type"` and `getError.message` errors because :

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null"

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined"

I can change store like that to fix the bug:

```js
const state = () => ({
  error: {
    message: undefined,
    type: undefined,
  },
});

// ...


const mutations = {
// ...

  [REMOVE_ERROR]: (state) => {
    state.error = {
      message: undefined,
      type: undefined,
    };
  },
};

...
```